# Git not merging file properly

Tags: git, merge

I have two branches on a project: developer (generic fix bugs) and branch1 (only new features). I work in both branches. Time to time I do merge branch1 with the developer branch.

In the last merge (with some conflicts), I notice that files on developer branch overrides totally the recently changed files of branch1, and lost new code.

This seems to be an anomaly to me, what is going wrong?

My doubt is that for some reason any file properties (not content) have changed in developer branch for some reason (permission or file encoding) and this is considered to be the last edit from git?

Comment: Can you give the snapshot of your console. It is not clear what you actually want to know ?

Comment: @Altius I am making merge with Zend Studio (eclipse), but tell me what comand to run and I can make a snapshot. Basically files changed in branch1 are getting overriden by developer files (that does not have been changed)

Comment: It difficult to guess without checking the command. It may mess more. No idea about to gain new code as don't know what stage your are. Try to check the commit history by `git log` or `git reflog`. Then reset git 
`reset --hard <commit>`
`git reset --soft HEAD@{1}`
`git commit -m "Reverting to the state of the project at <commit>`. Get back to your normal repo, then try to fix the merging. What I can suggest now